# Ubuntu 14.04 no launcher, no Dash ,unable to work

Tags: system-installation

After restart my ubuntu no launchbar, no Dash appear. i also cannot open terminal by typnh Ctrl + Alt + T.

i am follwing this [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/76951#76951)

but my problem is that i am also unable to connect internet via WiFi.
please help .

Comment: Have you installed some software lately? or changed any configuration?

Comment: no , i have not changed anything.

Comment: Please login using the recovery mode(you will get the option at startup under the heading **Advanced options**) and try to solve the problems according to the fix mentioned. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

then

```
setsid unity
```

It should work afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling vídeo drivers as well (ctrl alt t)  for terminal or control alt f1 so you can reinstall them via there.

If you somehow break vídeo drivers unity breaks because hardware vídeo aceleration isnt working.